# How to direct filename results of grep -l to vim editor

Tags: vim, grep

I would like to direct the results of a grep -l command to the vim editor.

E.g.

```
$ grep -l urls *.txt

foo1.txt
foo2.txt
foo3.txt
```

How to issue this command, and have the foo files open in vim?

Comment: take a look `:h :vimgrep`  it might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the output of the program as arguments to vim, not as input:

```
vim $(grep -l urls *.txt)
```

It is also possible to use xargs as mentioned by Duikboot

```
grep -l urls *.txt | xargs vim
```

Comment: Thanks Juan and Duikboot. For some reason, the xargs approach is not working nicely with git bash. However, Juan, your first solution above works nicely. Thanks to both!

Answer (score 4):

```
grep -l urls *.txt | xargs vim
```

xarg converts input from standard input into arguments to a command.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs

Answer (score 2):

You can combine `:help :args` and command substitution:

```
$ vim +ar\ $(grep -l urls *.txt)
```

Use `!!` to reuse the latest command:

```
$ vim +ar\ $(!!)
```

Answer (score 1):

**This opens vim with the filenames of files that end in `.txt` and contain the string "urls":**

```
grep -l urls *.txt | vim -
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From within vim you can redirect the output of any external command to the current buffer.

Try this !

```
:r!grep -l urls *.txt
```